# Listing post with this way "domain.com/taxonomy/category

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am triying to modify wordpress (version 3.3) to list post with one category and with one taxonomy.

I have got a taxonomy called "location". If I do example.org/location/canada, it works. Now I want url rewrite for example.org/location/canada/category/dogs, but i cant achieve it.

I added to functions.php this code:

function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

```
$new_rules = array(
    'location/(.+)/category/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?location=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
```

}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );

Also i have added this:

function eg_add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $new_vars = array( 'location' );

```
return array_merge( $new_vars, $query_vars );
```

}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'eg_add_query_vars' );

Answer (score 0):

Categories are taxonomy. So it depends on what taxonomy you want to use there. Tags, Categories, Custom Taxonomy.

If you want to create custom taxonomy, you can. Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Here is an example of registering custom taxonomy.

```
function people_init() {
// create a new taxonomy
register_taxonomy(
    'people',
    'post',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'People' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'person' ),
        'capabilities' => array('assign_terms'=>'edit_guides', 'edit_terms'=>'publish_guides')
    )
);
   } add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );
```

You will then need to edit your permalinks. Go to settings > Permalinks. Using the custom, change the URL to reflect how you want your paths to display.

If you like, you may enter custom structures for your category and tag URLs here. For example, using topics as your category base would make your category links like http://example.org/topics/uncategorized/. If you leave these blank the defaults will be used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i did not talked about that. I don't want change base name.

Comment: You edited your question to be more clear. Regardless, the answer reabove it relative. You've created custom taxonomy "location" and your category is "dogs"  you will need to edit your Permalinks to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, was my fault. I dont know edit my permalinks, i am reading documentation about permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

In functions.php (or in plugin if you want).

You must put this code to rewrite this url www.example.org/en/[mylocation]/de/[mycategory]

```
  add_action('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules'); 
  add_filter('category_rewrite_rules' , 'add_rules' ) ;  

  function flush_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

  }

  function add_rules($rules) 
  {
    /**
     * Loop em.
     * -------------------------------------------- */    

    $feed_rule  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]';
    $paged_rule = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]';
    $base_rule  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]';

    $rules['en/([^/]+)/de/([^/]+)/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = $feed_rule;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/de/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']                  = $paged_rule;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/de/([^/]+)/?$']                                    = $base_rule;

    $feed_rule2  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
    $paged_rule2 = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
    $base_rule2  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]';

    $rules['en/([^/]+)/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = $feed_rule2;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']                  = $paged_rule2;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/?$']                                  = $base_rule2;


    return $rules;

  }
```